# Using Faceboock graph api in nifi

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth, apache-nifi

I want   to get   user access token   from facebook  graph api,  but i can't pass  trough oAuth  autentification i  use  invokehttp processor(nifi processor ) inside  which i use  link like this :https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer%2Fcallback&scope=user_status%2Cuser_tagged_places%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_posts%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_relationships%2Cpages_messaging
 and  also   i  have  put basic  autentification  parameters inside  it,  when  i start  processor  i only get login  page  design in flowfile,  **what  should i  change to get  access  token prperly?** 
also  i  got  debug log   like this,  *I don't  know  what i  miss  to   fulfil this  process  properly*[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; are you somehow trying to perform a user login “in the background” here, or what? You have to redirect the user to the login dialog URL in their browser, this is nothing you can “automate” - getting a user access token requires user interaction.

Comment: Is  there any way   i can  do it  without  user  interacton?

Comment: No, that is not how it works - to get a fresh user access token, you need the user to be active in your app. (F.e. visiting a website app where you have the JS SDK embedded would be enough, if the user logged in to your app at some point before already, granted it all the necessary permissions, and is logged into Facebook in their browser at the same time - then the SDK will see to it that you have a fresh user access token.)